# Install Mac OS Monterey on Mac OS Ventura beta

Tags: macos

So, I updated to beta software but had no Time Machine to go to. If possible, is there a way I can install Mac OS Monterey with the app? The new OS took over my only hope with the reinstall option.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you will have to boot up to recovery mode, wipe the disk, then use internet recovery to reinstall Monterey. This will result in a loss of your data. If you do not want to lose your data, you could partition your disk, install Monterey on the new partition, and then use the Monterey partition until Ventura comes out as stable. Then you could upgrade your venture beta partition to stable venture & keep your data,